# How to create personalised prints as in this image?

Tags: software-recommendation

Can someone tell me what software I would use to create personalised prints where the words form a shape like a heart, or a babies pram or a rocket ship?

[image: example of words forming a baby's pram]

I've tried looking for myself but I don't know where to start. Thanks

Comment: Hi Nicola, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you please give us an example image of what you mean? Thanks!

Comment: <a href="http://s1338.photobucket.com/user/fluffleblossom/media/5E33B316-C3A8-4630-BD61-C1C2E02A1F9E_zpsrfz79mfd.jpg.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1338.photobucket.com/albums/o683/fluffleblossom/5E33B316-C3A8-4630-BD61-C1C2E02A1F9E_zpsrfz79mfd.jpg" border="0" alt=" photo 5E33B316-C3A8-4630-BD61-C1C2E02A1F9E_zpsrfz79mfd.jpg"/></a>

Comment: Thanks! You can add images straight into the body of your question by clicking the 'image' button and choosing your image, either online or on your computer. I went ahead and edited it in for you.

Comment: You could use practically anything to create this, it is basically an impossible question to answer. What would be most _efficient_ or a likely candidate would be vector-based programmes such as Illustrator and Inkscape. But pretty much anything will work.

Comment: I was thinking that some photo printing services have like a web app or desktop app or a tablet app, which might be the easiest for something like this, with little to no experience, assuming that the app isn't super restricted. From what I think I know, they usually have a selection of items where you can print, so you select like a post card template, or something and then they should allow you to write text and add images.

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of software you could make this with--any software that allows you to combine images and text would work, even (*shudder*) Word. As far as I can see, the example image is probably made in Illustrator. You could pull this off in Photoshop too, though.

For any software you choose goes that it's not a beginner's task. Especially getting things pixel-perfect is not easy. So if I were you, I'd choose a package that you have some experience with.